# MySQL: need to get a count of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I'm trying to do a SQL query which also spits out a number of qualifying rows from a different table, as a result.

Here's the current query, as inserted into sprintf:

> SELECT a.* FROM `websites` AS a
>   WHERE `website_id` = %d

Then, I have a query for retrieving the number of unique visits (from a table of visits) for a given site:

> SELECT * FROM `website_visits` WHERE
>   `website_id` = %d GROUP BY
>   `visitor_id`

Now, is there any way to insert that query inside the first one, so that I can retrieve the number of unique visits, as part of the result of the first query?  It would have to be something like this:

> SELECT a.*, (SELECT * FROM
>   `website_visits` AS b WHERE
>   b.`website_id` = a.`website_id` GROUP
>   BY `visitor_id`) AS unique_visits FROM
>   `websites` AS a WHERE `website_id` =
>   %d

But... as to the execution end, I'm stumped.  Any help you can provide is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the row count, add [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) to the query, like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name;
```

After this query, you can:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

To retrieve the row count.

(This retrieves the count in a cheap way; if you need the count as part of the rowset, you'll have to go with a subquery, like in your question.)

Comment: There are two different tables.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: Aha, missed that.  `found_rows()` won't do much good then

Answer (score 1):

This gives you all your website records, and for each one, a count of how many unique `visitor_id`s there are for that site.

```
SELECT a.*, (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.visitor_id)
    FROM website_visits AS b
    WHERE b.website_id = a.website_id) AS unique_visits
FROM websites AS a
WHERE website_id = %d
```

Comment: If you think there may be more than one record for a given `website_id`, then do you think `SELECT COUNT` would definitely be optimised? That is, in my opinion it most probably should, but you could rearrange the query to make it sure (surer at least).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the assistance.  Your COUNT (DISTINCT portion was massively helpful, though I ended up doing a separate query.  It was easier and less cpu-intensive than an inline query.  Like I said, your advice did come in handy.  Kudos!